# Quantize Image to 8 Gray Level

Tags: image-processing

Consider an image given as

```
[[ 20 40 20 20 ]
[ 80 90 150 0 ]
[ 40 90 200 100 ] 
[ 100 10 20 30 ]]
```

matrix. How can we quantize the given image to 8 gray levels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution: find the smallest and largest value (0 & 200).

Divide the range length by 8 to get 25. Divide each pixel by 25, throw away the remainder. The new values are now quantized to 8 gray levels.

Comment: Thanks for the solution :)